# Darktable - Rotate picture in lighttable mode using shortcut

Tags: darktable

I can't rotate a picture in the lightable mode through the shortcut. It seems that by default the shortcut is `bracketleft/right` but even if I change this, still doesn't work.

It is highly necessary to make a preselection of my pictures, since using the button looses the focus on the main image and another click is necessary on the picture to reactivate the left/right keys which is not smooth as a workflow.

I am not sure it's a bug or if I missed something. Asking here first then I'll report if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bracket shortcuts you're describing only work in darkroom mode. If you want to use them in lighttable mode, you can set them in the shortcuts tab of preferences under "modules>selected image[s]". These operations don't have keyboard shortcuts by default, for some reason...